# Lua multidimensional table call

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I seem to be having a problem with multidimensional tables (arrays?) on Lua. I have one that looks something like this:

```
arr =
{
  "stats" = {
         "23" = {
                "1" = { 
                  "account_id" = "10",
                  "info" = {
                            "name" = "john"
                           }
                      }
                 }
             }
}
```

and whenever I try to access some info using like:

```
local entry = "23"
print(arr['stats'][entry]['1'])
```

or

```
print(arr['stats'][entry]['1']['info']['name'])
```

I get nil values, is mixing strings with variables when calling tables even allowed? any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The second example prints `john`, after fixing the syntax in the definition of `are` to use `["stats"] =` etc.

Comment: the data is the result of an unserialized plain-text array and why is using something like:

Comment: *The data is the result of an unserialized plain-text array. Why is using something like:print(tostring(arr['stats'][entry])) giving me a nil value?

Comment: As lhf points out, in your code, the syntax of `arr` is incorrect. Fix that and it would work just fine. If the data isn't exactly like what you put in the question, like you said in the comment, then show an example that people could reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that lua does not accepts things like

```
arr = { "string" = "value"}
```

so, either you do

```
arr = { string = "value"}
```

or you do

```
arr = {["string"] = value}
```

That way, your table must be rewritten as this, in order to run on lua 5.3 interpreter:

```
arr =
{
   stats =
   {
      ["23"] = 
      {
        ["1"] =
        {
          account_id = "10",
          info = 
          {
            name = "john"
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

doing this, your line

```
print(arr['stats'][entry]['1']['info']['name'])
```

runs fine.

Also, it is not good practice to use brackets when you can use a dot. It is not that your script will not run otherwise, but the code gets a lot more legible and easier to debug if you wirte that line like this:

```
print(arr.stats[entry]['1'].info.name)
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: did Lua ever allow to have a string as a field name without brackets?

Comment: I remember doing that in Lua 5.1, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: You are mistaken, Lua never allowed string literal as a key without bracketing it first.